# Simultaneous client-certificate and username authentication of a SOAP web service under WCF

Tags: c#, authentication, wcf, wcf-security

I have trouble authenticating to a SOAP web service, which requires simultaneous authentication with a client certificate and a username.

The target service, basically, supports three modes of authentication:

- username + password — this works for me well, using `BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport`
- certificate-only — can't use this mode for various reasons
- certificate + username — (note that there's no password in this case, it's left blank) I can't get this mode working.

In each case, it's HTTPS with TLS 1.2.

In fact, **I don't know how to configure the binding and authentication settings to describe such authentication mode in WCF.** So far I experimented with various `BasicHttpsBinding` configurations and `CustomBinding` setups including that described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25644118/245183).

In the code below, when both `endpointConfig.Username` and `endpointConfig.ClientCertificate` are specified, I build a `CustomBinding` based on examples I was able to google, but it won't work. The client does send the correct certificate to the server, the server replies with a Change Cipher Spec message, and the client terminates the TLS connection.

[image: Wireshark capture]

The farthest I could get is the following error messages:

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'ws1c.czebox.cz'.

> Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'ws1c.czebox.cz'.

The code for constructing the service client looks like this:

```
// prepare binding
Binding binding;
// NOTE A username alone is sufficient for Basic authentication e.g. when logging-in to a DataBox using the HostCert method
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(endpointConfig.Username) && endpointConfig.ClientCertificate != null)
{
    // client certificate and username + password
    // the below code is experimental and just doesn't work (yields the first error mentioned above)
    var tb = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
    tb.MaxReceivedMessageSize = MaxSupportedMessageSize;
    tb.RequireClientCertificate = true;
    tb.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;
    var ub = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
    binding = new CustomBinding(ub, tb);
}
else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(endpointConfig.Username))
{
    // username + password
    var b = new BasicHttpsBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
    b.MaxReceivedMessageSize = MaxSupportedMessageSize;
    b.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
    binding = b;
}
else if (endpointConfig.ClientCertificate != null)
{
    // client certificate
    var b = new BasicHttpsBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
    b.MaxReceivedMessageSize = MaxSupportedMessageSize;
    b.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
    binding = b;
}
else
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}

// prepare endpoint identity
EndpointIdentity identity = null;
X509Certificate2 cert = null;
if (endpointConfig.ClientCertificate != null)
{
    var clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
    clientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
        endpointConfig.ClientCertificate.StoreLocation,
        endpointConfig.ClientCertificate.StoreName,
        endpointConfig.ClientCertificate.FindBy,
        endpointConfig.ClientCertificate.FindValue);
    cert = clientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate;
    identity = EndpointIdentity.CreateX509CertificateIdentity(cert);
}

// prepare endpoint address
var address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(endpointConfig.EndpointUrl), identity);

// create connector 
var connector = new dmInfoPortTypeClient(binding, address);

// setup username + password authentication
// NOTE Password may be empty when logging-in to a DataBox using the HostCert method
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(endpointConfig.Username))
{
    connector.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = endpointConfig.Username;
    connector.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = endpointConfig.Password;
}

// setup client-certificate authentication
if (endpointConfig.ClientCertificate != null)
{
    connector.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;
}
```

Note that I have zero control of the server. It's a government service, can't negotiate anything.

Running on .NET 4.7.x. Can upgrade to 4.8, but can't move to .NET Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Self-answering with the solution I've figured out based on extensive debugging and diagnostics. Better answers are welcome.)*

It turns out the situation is almost the same as described in [this Q&A pair](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21341899/245183). However, in my case I am building the WCF endpoint programmatically, avoiding XML configuration.

#### 1) Correct custom binding

For the certificate + username option, the following code constructs a working custom binding:

```
// HTTPS transport with basic authentication and required client certificate
// note that AuthenticationSchemes.Certificate doesn't work, the server requires
// Basic authentication
var tb = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
tb.MaxReceivedMessageSize = MaxSupportedMessageSize;
tb.RequireClientCertificate = true;
tb.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;

// encoding: the server uses SOAP 1.1. which results in the MIME content-type text/xml
// note that by default, the encoding is SOAP 1.2, which implies the content-type
// application/soap+xml not compatible with the server, resulting in an exception
var enc = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);

// transport security: pass username over transport; it is necessary to allow
// unsecured responses; don't know why, but without this setting it won't work
var ub = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
ub.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;

// construct the binding
binding = new CustomBinding(enc, ub, tb);
```

Note: The are two aspects, which are, IMO, custom to my specific case, so don't fit in a general solution:

- using an explicit encoding denoting `MessageVersion.Soap11` for SOAP 1.1; by default, the encoding is `MessageVersion.Soap12` for SOAP 1.2
- enabling unsecured responses using the `SecurityBindingElement.EnableUnsecuredResponse`

#### 2) No endpoint identity

The code section commented with `// prepare endpoint identity` was wrong, incorrectly using the *client-side* certificate as the one WCF is supposed to expect to receive from the *server*.

#### 3) WCF tracing

When diagnosing the problem, what enabling WCF tracing was instrumental. The following can be used in `app.config` to enable logging:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <!-- use for WCF diagnostis: WCF tracing and message logging -->
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel"
        switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
        propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
            <add name="traceListener"
            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
            initializeData= "D:\Logs\WCF-Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
            <add name="messages"
            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
            initializeData="D:\Logs\WCF-Messages.svclog" />
        </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```